# Why are my form fields, built using Drupal Next.js Webforms, not displaying the Help Text?

Tags: next.js, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-webform

I'm running decoupled Drupal with [Next.js Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/next_webform). In the CMS, I gave the First Name form field a `help-text` value. In the **Webform preview**, this `help-text` feature displays...

[image]

...but on the actual page, it doesn't (*and this is true of all fields I assign help-text to, by the way*):

[image]

So, I took a look at the React component in `Webform.tsx`...

```html
// ...
    return (
        <div className={styles["webform"]}>
          {loading ? <ImageGridLoader /> : null}
          {!message && !loading ? (
            <Webform
              id={id}
              data={webform}
              className={styles["webform__form"]}
              noValidate={false}
              onSubmit={handleSubmit}
              customComponents={{
                textfield: withCustomStyles(
                  components.textfield,
                  fieldProps,
                  labelProps,
                  wrapperProps
                ),
                // ...
```

...and I verified that the `webform` object above, which delivers the form its data **does in fact** contain the `help-text` values:

[image]

But, if `help-text` still isn't displaying, then it suggests that either the data isn't getting passed to `components.textfield` correctly, or the `textfield` isn't making use of this data. As I understand, `textfield` is the built-in component that comes with the Webform or Next.js Webform module. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find much information about how to work with this component, as the documentation for Next.js Webform is limited, and I'm still new to decoupled Drupal.

I would appreciate it if somebody could point me in the right direction as to how to get Webform fields to display the `help-text`.

*Am I missing a line in Webforms to pass in the right data to the form fields? Must I toggle something on for textfield? Is this a configuration issue? Do the fields just not support help-text, and I need a plugin, or to create a custom field component?*

Any guidance would be welcome.